# Загрузить баннер через скрипт

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Подскажите как сделать загрузку через javascrip, допустим я на сайт разместил вот такой код:

```
<script src="http://site.ru/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Мне надо, чтобы он грузил баннер у меня допустим написан обычный баннер:

```
<a href="site2.ru"><img src="site2.ru\img.png"></a>
```

Подскажите, как заставить скрипт грузить данный код ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В скрипте написать

```
document.write('<a href="site2.ru"><img src="site2.ru\img.png"></a>');
```